# Global CRUD Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, crud, ember-cli

I was wondering if someone could give me brief direction. I'm making an app that I want to be able to take notes from anywhere I'm at in the app (CRUD). I'm rendering my presentations in my application controller using {{render}} but I'm not sure how to put the full crud operations there as well. This is what I have so far:

-- **Presentation Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PresentationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    edit: function () {
      this.transitionToRoute('presentation.edit');
    },
    save: function () {
      var presentation = this.get('model');
      // this will tell Ember-Data to save/persist the new record
      presentation.save();
      // then transition to the current user
      this.transitionToRoute('presentation', presentation);
    },
    delete: function () {
      // this tells Ember-Data to delete the current user
      this.get('model').deleteRecord();
      this.get('model').save();
      // then transition to the users route
      this.transitionToRoute('presentations');
    }
  }
});

export default PresentationController;
```

-- **Presentations Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PresentationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    sendMessage: function ( message ) {
      if ( message !== '') {
        console.log( message );
      }
    }
  }
});

export default PresentationsController;
```

-- **Model**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Presentation = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    note: DS.attr('string')
});
```

-- **Presentations Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PresentationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('presentation');
  }
});

export default PresentationsRoute;
```

-- **Presentation Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var PresentationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('presentation', params.id);
  }
});

export default PresentationRoute;
```

-- **Application Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('category');
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('product', this.store.find('product'));
    controller.set('presentation', this.store.find('presentation'));
  }
});
```

-- **Application HBS**

```
<section class="main-section">
      <div id="main-content">
        {{#link-to "presentations.create" class="create-btn expand" tagName="button"}} Add presentation {{/link-to}}
        {{render 'presentations' presentation}}
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
  </section>
```

-- **Presentations HBS**

```
{{#each presentation in controller}}
    {{#link-to 'presentation' presentation tagName='li'}}
      {{presentation.title}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

-- **Presentation HBS**

```
{{outlet}}
<div class="user-profile">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <p>{{note}}</p>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button {{action "edit" }}>Edit</button>
    <button {{action "delete" }}>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a mixin? Make a simple crud mixin with the actions and extend your routes with it.

Comment: "but I'm not sure how to put the full crud operations there as well" What exactly are you saying the problem is here? Where do you want to put CRUD operations? In the application controller?

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to create a presentation / add notes to it from anywhere in the application. So if I'm on some static page, I can open a sidebar (while staying on the static page) and see a list of presentations. Then in that side bar create new presentations. Then when I click on a presentation I can view/edit the note for the presentation.

Currently, I can see my list of presentations anywhere in the app. I'm not sure how to do the rest as right now I'm just navigating to the presentation route

I'm not familiar with mixins, I'll look that up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you're describing is a modal of sorts. It'll be accessible no matter what page (route) you're viewing, and you will be able to perform actions within this modal (creating notes, editing notes, deleting notes, etc) without leaving or affecting the current page being displayed in the background. Essentially, what this means is that you should leave the router alone, since the router is what controls the current page, and you don't want to affect that. You're not going to want to have any `{{#link-to}}` or `transitionTo` or `transitionToRoute` calls, nor any presentation-related routes or outlets.

Instead, you're going to have to handle everything at the controller and view level. This is where components really come in handy, as they're great for encapsulation if you use them correctly. Inside of presentations.hbs, I'd use components to represent each of the presentations:

```
{{#each presentation in controller}}
  {{individual-presentation presentationModelBinding="presentation"}}
{{/each}}
```

Note that you'll need a corresponding `IndividualPresentationComponent` object that extends `Ember.Component`. Going further, inside of individual-presentation.hbs, I'd have code similar to what you have now, but with allowances for various CRUD operations:

```
{{#if editing}}
  {{input value=presentationModel.title}}
  {{textarea value=presentationModel.note}}
{{else}}
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <p>{{note}}</p>
{{/if}}
<div class="btn-group">
  {{#if editing}}
    <button {{action "save" }}>Save</button>
  {{else}}
    <button {{action "edit" }}>Edit</button>
  {{/if}}
  <button {{action "delete" }}>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Note that the context for a component's template is the component itself, not some other controller. Similarly, actions fired inside of a component's template are direct to the component's `actions` hash. So your `IndividualPresentationComponent` will need to look like this somewhat:

```
IndividualPresentationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['user-profile'],

  actions: {
    save: function () {
      this.sendAction('save', this.get('presentationModel'));
      this.set('editing', false);
    },

    edit: function () {
      this.set('editing', true);
    },

    delete: function () {
      this.sendAction('delete', this.get('presentationModel'));
    }
  }
});
```

Notice I'm using `sendAction` here. This is how components communicate with the outside world. To get this to work, go back your presentations.hbs and intercept the actions like so:

```
{{#each presentation in controller}}
  {{individual-presentation presentationModelBinding="presentation"
                            save="savePresentation"
                            delete="deletePresentation"}}
{{/each}}
```

Here you're basically saying that if the component sends the "save" action, you want to handle it with your controller's "savePresentation" action, and if the component sends the "delete" action, you want to handle it with your controller's "deletePresentation" action. So your presentations-controller.js will need to implement those actions:

```
var PresentationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    savePresentation: function (presentationModel) {
      ...
    },

    deletePresentation: function (presentationModel) {
      ...
    },
  }
});
```

And you can delete `PresentationController`, since all of its functionality is now handled directly by your `IndividualPresentationComponent` and your `PresentationsController`.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect such a great answer, thank you so much! This gave me a much better understanding of components and to be more conscious of what I should be utilizing in Ember for what I need.

This worked like a charm +1